# Efficient querying for equality of ranges in an integer array

Tags: algorithm, performance, time

Given an positive integer array of size `n`, it is expected to find whether two ranges gives as queries are equal or not. Two ranges are considered equal if the all the elements present in range 1 are present in range 2 and in the same count as well.

Example:

```
1 2 5 3 5 1 2
```

Queries:

```
[1,3] and [5,7]
[2,4] and [3,5]
```

Answers:

```
Yes
No
```

A naive solution can be suggested in the following way:
1. For every query, make two copies of the array that store each of the ranges `O(n)`.
2. Then sort each of them. `O(n*logn)`
3. Then compare element by element and return `true` or `false`. `O(n)`

So the complexity of the solution is `O(q*n*logn)`, where `q` is the number of queries. Is it possible for an efficient solution to this problem?

PS: The constraints of all the variables `n`, `q` and the array elements are `<=10^5`.

Comment: Are there any space restrictions? You can always trade-off time for space.

Comment: @biziclop ... you can safely take upto `50MB` of space.

Answer (score 1):

Though there may be other approaches as well to solve this one, below approach will work well to solve this in O(N). (for x number of times if queries come then O(xN) which can be optimised by caching the results of queries too, just the query range and its result)

For our ease lets name the starting and ending element in queries as 
`range1StartIndex` , `range2StartIndex`, `range1EndIndex` and `range2EndIndex`.

1. See if the difference between end and start elements of both the ranges are not equal, of so then return "No" else move to next step.

( If the differences in both the range are equal then we need to process the array elements).

2. Initialize a HashMap, lets name it `countMap`. Iterate the array from `range1StartIndex` till `range1EndIndex` and put in map as entry of each character encountered and its total number of occurances. Move to next step.
3. Iterate the array from `range2StartIndex` till `range2EndIndex`. As an character is encountered see if it is present in the `countMap`. If it is not present or if its count is 0 then return "No".  If it is present decrement the count by one and move to next step.
4. Iterate the keys of the `countMap` , if any key has a count greater than 1 , return "No", else move to next step.
5. return "Yes". Exit.

Comment: You mean `O(q*N)`. But in this case too seeing the range of integers possible (`<=10^5`), isn't it better to have a `logn` factor rather than going through the whole hash table for every query? (point no. `4`).

Comment: You can build a segemnt tree with nodes representing the range and containg the hashcode of the numbers in that range. You will need to compare only in case tge hashcode contained by the nodes represnting the queries are same else you know they are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's start with the array: `1 2 5 3 5 1 2`

This array has four distinct elements (let's call this number `d`), and we can pre-calculate four lists like this:

```
D[1]: 1 1 1 1 1 2 2
D[2]: 0 1 1 1 1 1 2
D[3]: 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
D[5]: 0 0 1 1 2 2 2
```

These contain the number of each distinct element encountered up to that point. The size of this list is obviously `d*n`.

Once that's done, for each query you can simply check how many of each distinct element `E` there is in the range `(x,y)` by calculating `D[E][y]-D[E][x])`. Two ranges will contain exactly the same elements iff for all distinct elements this difference is identical.

Obviously this solution works best if the number of distinct elements is relatively low compared to `n`, with the per-query cost being `O(distinct values)`.

*I also omitted a couple of fairly simple optimisations, like if the two ranges aren't of equal length, or bailing out early if any of the differences is found to be different.*

---

**Update:**

You can also store the same map like this:

```
D'[1]: 0 5
D'[2]: 1 6
D'[3]: 3
D'[5]: 2 4
```

This map only contains the indices of where the original `D[]` would change. The size of this map is always `n`, but calculating `D[E][y] - D[E][x]` now involves a binary search, which still maintains an `O(n)` worst case per-query cost.

But it still isn't ideal for queries of short ranges, where the naive comparison of each item will yield a better result.

Comment: Considering the worst case scenario, the memory complexity is `(10^5)^2`, which is `10^10`......way greater than `50MB` I guess :).

Comment: @yobro97 Yes, this is specifically for cases where the number of distinct values is fairly low but you've got to serve a lot of queries. Note though that as `d` rises, the amount of bits required to store each value of `D` decreases. In fact if all the elements are unique, you only have to store a map of the index of each element.

Comment: @biziclop can you explain this 'D[E][y]-D[E][x])' with an example?